# SED command is not working

Tags: shell, sed

I am facing some problem in below command

```
INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH="/app/csa/sumit/xyz.out"

sed -i "s/^$InputFile=.*/$InputFile='${INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH}'/g" dashboard.prf

ERROR : sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'
```

When i am using the value of INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH without using "/" then it is working fine..but when i use "/" in the value of variable INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH then it is giving error. I know that problem with "/" character. But can any one help me to resolve this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To use variables inside `sed`, you need to wrap it with `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: You can use `@` instead of `/` for the separator for the `s` operator in sed. Bear in mind that `$` is the end of line special character so it may not do what you think it does

Comment: Thanks fedorqui... I have updated the code..but still it is not working

Comment: Thanks Petesh... I didn't get your point. Can you please update the sed command.

Comment: @Petesh: depends on the RE engine, but generally `$` only means end-of-line at the end of an RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@` character instead of `/` for the separator, so your code would look like:

```
INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH="/app/csa/sumit/xyz.out"

sed -i 's@^$InputFile=.*@$InputFile='${INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH}'@g' dashboard.prf
```

You can use `sed -n` and add a trailing `p` to test regular expressions without modifying the file in question and only displaying if it matches, so for example:

```
sed -n 's@^$InputFile=.*@$InputFile='${INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH}'@gp' dashboard.prf
```

and it will only print if it matches. It is **not** a good idea to combine `-n` and `-i`, as you end up with a very small file :(

Comment: `$` only means "end of line" when it is at the end of the regular expression.  The `sed` you give works find (on GNU sed version 4.2.1)

Comment: @cdarke thanks for that, I had noticed and struck out the paragraph already

Comment: What if your file name contains "@"? The only characters that cannot appear in a file name are the nul char (`\0`) and `/` and the latter appears in directory paths so you can't use that so the only delimiter character you can use in sed when working on directory paths is the nul char but there is no way I know of to get a nul char into a sed command unless you use $'\0' within double quotes but then you introduce a whole other set of sed issues.

Comment: @EdMorton I accept the point that it's swapping one forbidden character for another. I tend to pick characters from the 'not very often seen in a filename set', and if you have control over the input file, this is doable. You could iterate through a large set of potential separator characters checking if one will work in that case, but in that case, I'd swap to a perl/python solution

Comment: seems like a lot of work to try various characters for sed and even if you find one that works for the initial test set, it might not work in future. perl and python aren't available on all UNIX installations while awk is and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk. The benefit of sed's -i is far outweighed by sed issues with using shell variables like the ones you've already encountered:

```
INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH="/app/csa/sumit/xyz.out"

awk -v file="$InputFile" -v path="$INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH" '
    { gsub("^"file"=.*", file"="path); print }
' dashboard.prf > tmp && mv tmp dashboard.prf
```

Note that, like any sed solution, the above is using the $InputFile variable in a regular expression context so if thatvariable contains RE metacharacters like "." then you could get undesirable matches, e.g. "foo.bar" would match "fooXbar" as well as "foo.bar". In sed there is NO robust solution for that (do not listen to anyone telling you to escape RE metacharacters as it CANNOT be done reliably), but in awk you can use index() to match on a string instead of a regexp, e.g.:

```
awk -v file="$InputFile" -v path="$INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH" '
    index($0,file"=")==1{ $0 = file"="path) } { print }
' dashboard.prf > tmp && mv tmp dashboard.prf
```

I would use the "index()" approach if I were you to avoid any surprises in future if/when your input file contents change.

If your awk doesn't support -v for assigning variables then:

```
awk '
    index($0,file"=")==1{ $0 = file"="path) } { print }
' file="$InputFile" path="$INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH" dashboard.prf > tmp && mv tmp dashboard.prf
```

or if you're happy with a sed solution then you must be happy with an RE-based solution so:

```
awk '
    { gsub("^"file"=.*", file"="path); print }
' file="$InputFile" path="$INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH" dashboard.prf > tmp && mv tmp dashboard.prf
```

and finally here's the RE-based solution for avid golfers:

```
awk '{gsub("^"f"=.*",f"="p)}1' f="$InputFile" p="$INPUT_FILE_NAME_PATH" dashboard.prf > tmp && mv tmp dashboard.prf
```

Comment: This is definitely a better solution. If it wasn't for the fact that I end up having to install `gawk` explicitly on debian systems to get it to work with various packages that rely on `awk` being `gawk` instead of it being `mawk`.

Comment: There is nothing gawk-specific in the above. If I were you I'd get some awk other than mawk as mawk is minimal-featured for (almost always unnecessary) increased execution speed but even with mawk the only thing in the above that MIGHT not work is using -v to assign variables and that's trivially worked around by assigning them after the command. I'll update my answer to show that.